# Adding a value to the column while importing a CSV file in CSV

Tags: sas

Right now I'm importing a CSV file using below code...and then updating a column(Date) with a macro variable(RunDate).

```
%let RunDATE = 25JAN2015;
data Import (KEEP = Date ID);
infile "&infl." delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2;
    informat Id $22. ;
    informat Date $1. ;
        format Id $22. ;
        format Date $1. ;
        input Id $ Date $;
run;

Data Import ;
Set Import(drop=Date); 
    date="&Rundate"d; format date date9.;
Run;
```

Is it possible to achieve this in one step like updating the column(Date) with a macro variable while importing the CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, as long as you're using a data step to read in the file (as you are). You're welcome to do any normal data step code in a step that is inputting from a file.

```
%let RunDATE = 25JAN2015;
data Import (KEEP = Date ID);
infile "&infl." delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2;
    informat Id $22. ;
    informat __dropme $1. ;
        format Id $22. ;
        format __dropme $1. ;
        input Id $ __dropme $;
    date="&Rundate"d; format date date9.;
    drop __dropme;
Run;
```